# Object difference DSPFD vs qsys2.systables

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a strange observation, that's I'd like to share.

There's an object (it's a logical file) on my system that when displayed on 5250 shows following characteristic:

- Maximum record length . . . . . . . . . . . :             **3120**
- and then when SQL qsys2.SYSTABLES it states:
  Row_length: **32120**

Where does that (may) come from?

**The PF that this LF is based on have row lenght < 3120.**

On top of that I can say that if I transfer (*SAVF over FTP) this view (and its dependencies) to mirrored (QuickEDD*) system then:

- DSPFD which states: Maximum record length . . . . . . . . . . . :             **3120**
- and qsys2.SYSTABLES which states: **3120**

*same thing happens with QuickEDD - it eventually throws an error (file is synchronised but different :) )

Any idea ?

Comment: We need more information here. show us a screen shot of your results. Also show us a list of columns with data types and length/precision/scale. Also, show the DDS that is used to define the LF and the PF (as text, not an image).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from IBMs documentation

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=views-systables#rbafzcatsystbls__recln

[image]

*1)* ***The length is the number of bytes passed in database buffers***, not the internal storage length.

It seems like Data Management decided to buffer ten records at a time, plus a few control bytes on the primary system, where there is read activity on the file. On the mirrored system, Data Management decided not to buffer.